# SQL Server Circular Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables, in that I want to fetch records from all 4 and aggregate the values

I have these tables

[image]

I am expecting this output

[image]

but getting this output as a Cartesian product

[image]

It is multiplying the expenses and allocation

Here is my query

```
select 
    a.NAME, b.P_NAME,
    sum(a.DURATION) DURATION,
    sum(b.[EXP]) EXPEN 
from
    (select 
         e.ID, a.P_ID, e.NAME, a.DURATION DURATION 
     from 
         EMPLOYEE e 
     inner join 
         ALLOCATION a ON e.ID = a.E_ID) a
inner join 
    (select 
         p.P_ID, e.E_ID, p.P_NAME, e.amt [EXP] 
     from 
         PROJECT p 
     inner join 
         EXPENSES e ON p.P_ID = e.P_ID) b ON a.ID = b.E_ID 
                                          and a.P_ID = b.P_ID 
group by 
    a.NAME, b.P_NAME
```

Can anyone suggest something about this.

Comment: Expenses and allocation bear no (1-1) relation with each other, correct?

Comment: You need to group the expenses and allocation separately!

Comment: yes 1-1 i needed. but it is multiplying the expenses and allocation time whenever a double entry of project appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I got the answer what I want from some modification in the query

The above query is also working like a charm and have done some modification to the original query and got the answer

Just have to group by the inner queries and then join the queries it will then not showing Cartesian product

Here is the updated one

```
select a.NAME,b.P_NAME,sum(a.DURATION) DURATION,sum(b.[EXP]) EXPEN from

(select e.ID,a.P_ID, e.NAME,sum(a.DURATION) DURATION from EMPLOYEE e inner join ALLOCATION a
ON e.ID=a.E_ID group by e.ID,e.NAME,a.P_ID) a

inner join 

(select p.P_ID,e.E_ID, p.P_NAME,sum(e.amt) [EXP] from PROJECT p inner join EXPENSES e 
ON p.P_ID=e.P_ID group by p.P_ID,p.P_NAME,e.E_ID) b 

ON a.ID=b.e_ID and a.P_ID=b.P_ID group by a.NAME,b.P_NAME
```

Showing the correct output

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```
SELECT e.Name,p.Name,COALESCE(d.Duration,0),COALESCE(exp.Expen,0)
FROM
   Employee e
      CROSS JOIN
   Project p
      LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT E_ID,P_ID,SUM(Duration) as Duration FROM Allocation
    GROUP BY E_ID,P_ID) d
      ON
        e.E_ID = d.E_ID and
        p.P_ID = d.P_ID
      LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT E_ID,P_ID,SUM(AMT) as Expen FROM Expenses
    GROUP BY E_ID,P_ID) exp
      ON
         e.E_ID = exp.E_ID and
         p.P_ID = exp.P_ID
WHERE
    d.E_ID is not null or
    exp.E_ID is not null
```

I've tried to write a query that will produce results where e.g. there are rows in `Expenses` but no rows in `Allocations` (or vice versa) for some particular `E_ID`,`P_ID` combination.

Comment: where i was lacking. can you elaborate so that i will have some idea about it

Comment: @AMS - the basic problem is that you were joining to `Expenses` and `Allocation` *as if* `E_ID` and `P_ID` were sufficient to act as a key in those tables - but since there can be multiple rows in those tables for the same `E_ID` and `P_ID` values, they end up joining together in all combinations that match - so two rows in each table end up producing four rows in the output, before the aggregation occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Use left join in select query by passing common id for all table